# C program:output seems confusing

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<conio.h>  
#define SQUARE(x) (x*x)  
void main()  
{  
    clrscr();  
    int i=3,j,k;  
    j=SQUARE(i++);  
    k=SQUARE(++i);  
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d",j,k,i);  
    getch();  
}
```

Answer confusing: 9 49 7
I was thinking j=3*4=12, k=6*7=42 , i=7
What is happening?did i miss something?
(x*x)=((x)*(x)) same here.it doesn't matter.

Comment: This is an *exact* textual duplicate of an existing question. These people just seem to dump their exam question to SO.

Comment: @Jens, this must be some _new_ meaning of the word "exact" that I was previously unaware of. That "dupe" has different macro name, different arguments, different number of calls, different variable names and different output. In fact, the only real similarity seems to be the structure (simple main) and the use of archaic Turbo C (which Indian unis seem to like for some bizarre reasons). I can only assume you were trained at the SCO-Blepp institute of software similarity analysis :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two lines:

```
#define SQUARE(x) (x*x)  
j=SQUARE(i++);
```

translates into:

```
j = (i++ * i++);
```

which is undefined behaviour. You are not permitted to modify a variable twice without an intervening sequence point (and `*` is not a sequence point).

You're better off using something like:

```
inline int SQUARE (int x) { return x * x; }
```

What's probably happening is that the increments are happening together after or before the multiplication is done, effectively giving you:

```
i = 3;                  // i = 3
j = i * i; i++; i++;    // j = 9, i = 5
++i; ++i; k = i * i;    // i = 7, k = 49
```

But keep in mind that's what's happening in *this case.* An implementation is free to do it some other way since you're breaking the rules. In fact, it can format your hard disk if it wants to. That is the nature of undefined behaviour, defined as (my italics):

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes *no* requirements.
>
> NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely *with unpredictable results,* to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Comment: Yes, annex C lists the sequence points and `*` is not one of them.

Comment: let me clear to you folks,above code compiles and works fine.so how does it undefined in C.?

Comment: It's undefined because the standard says so. Put it through a decent compiler like `gcc - Wall -std=c99` to get `warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined`. The fact that it compiles on a particular implementation (the ancient Turbo C by the looks of it) is not relevant. You can _do_ it, just be aware that the results may not always be what you expect.

Comment: Yes am using turbo C and but one of my friend using gcc says it gives same answer on it also.what should i do to answer such type of quetions in exams.?thanks

Comment: State that the behaviour is undefined and shouldn't be used. It's that simple. The behaviour can change with a different compiler, different version of the compiler, day of the week or on a blue moon. There are ways to calculate them which delivers guaranteed results, use those. With inline functions and enums, macros can really be limited nowadays to just compile-time flags.

Comment: @Arjun: The problem is that the code *doesn't* work fine; it's not giving you the answer you expect.  "Undefined" doesn't mean "won't compile and run", it just means that the compiler is free to handle that situation any way it feels like.